# pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have two distinct documents in list. I am trying to use bulk update with upsert for them but getting error like batch op errors occurred.
I have created new collection and currently no record is there.
I am not able to understand why I am getting this error.
if collection is empty it should insert new records.

Below is the data which I am using

```
[
    {'_id':{'Material': '445673', 'loc': '308', 'ConfigLevel': 'Rules'},'Configuration':"Something"},
    {'_id':{'Material': '142456', 'loc': '308', 'ConfigLevel': 'Rules'},'Configuration':"Something"}
]
```

This is my pymongo code below

```
bulk = db.RPT_Table.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for record in siteProductDataList:
print record['_id']
FilterDict = {'_id': record['_id']}
SetDict = {'$set' : {
                'Configuration' : record['Configuration']
            } }
bulk.find(FilterDict).upsert().update(SetDict)
result = bulk.execute()
```

Any body has face this kind of issues before?
I know this error comes when duplicate _id is there. But in my case it is different id's

Comment: You seem to be missing some indentation here. Can we presume that everything above the `result` is actually meant to be in the loop? Can you fix that in your question? What error exactly? The `result` will have details of the specific error which is occurring. You might have accidentally indexed a different field for all we know, so we need to see the error. Also you really should be using `bulk_write()` rather than directly using the bulk operations interface. It's better for client code since it knows to "downgrade" where needed.

Comment: The absence of a 'Configuration' key in record will result to a `KeyError` when evaluating the binding to `SetDict`. Do you mean to use `record['data']`?